# How to go through menu items and tap actions in tasker

Tags: android, automation, tasker

Being an amateur user, I just stick to basic operations on tasker like creating a zooper widget and toggling settings, running ussd. But I was thinking about interacting with output of the ussd code, I don't know if it is possible but I hope someone can clarify me on this.. 
I run the code *#*#4636#*#* very often to force WCDMA through the test menu, it takes two clicks after dialing the code, 1. Tapping "Phone information" which is the first option.
2. Scrolling down a bit and opening a list named "set preferred network type" where I can select WCDMA ONLY.
Now can this whole thing be automated.

Note: The normal system settings where simply selecting carrier mode or toggling it through tasker doesn't work as I think my phone automatically switches the network to EDGE as soon as I enter my room and I must do this toggle manually through test menu(*#*#4636#*#*) even if the usual system settings say it's in 3g.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

To open the hidden menu, use following intent:

`action: android.intent.action.MAIN`

`package: com.android.settings`

`class: com.android.settings.TestingSettings`

and for clicking items I would highly recommend using [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput), as it gives you far more control than built-in tasker functions. It also has a very user-friendly "Easy Setup", that basically walks you through what (and) where needs to be clicked, based on either coordinates, id, label or position :)

So in case of selecting "phone information" using `AutoInput`:

1. add new tasker `action`
2. select `plug-in`
3. select `AutoInput`
4. select `AutoInput Action`
5. select `Easy Setup` to be guided through, or in `Manual Setup` enter following

   - Action: `click`
   - field type: `list`
   - field position: `1`

and similarly for next items :)

Comment: Hey Tomaski thank you very much, autoinput worked like a charm. I actually selected the testing app directly from tasker to launch and initially setup run shell command as "input swipe x y x y" but it was not stable, autoinput did it very well selecting the Fields instead of coordinates. However I didn't find a way to press "HOME" button after the execution. For now I'm using two "Back" input actions.

Comment: `HOME` is to be found in plug-in -> AutoInput -> Global Action :)